# Create Live ISO from installed Ubuntu with data for future install like SUPER OS

Tags: iso, restore

is there any way to backup as ISO of my current Ubuntu OS with all installed data like SUPER OS. Or, anyway to make like live ISO from my installed Ubuntu with apps, that i will installed it later with installed data,apps etc in my PC or someone else. 
If there any solution please reply.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The Systemback tool allows you to create restore points, backups, and live images of a running system.

I use it to make a "Master Backup" if something is really broken. Systemback creates a full system image for restore, either save it to USB or create a bootable Live CD (ISO file) with option to restore full system.

You won't find Systemback in the standard repositories, so you must first add the repo with the command:

`sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:nemh/systemback`

Update Repo:

`sudo apt-get update`

Install Systemback:

`sudo apt-get install systemback`

Run Systemback from Dash, if you need any other guidlines on that tool ask here or check the Google how to run it, there are some usefull guides on it.

EDIT: Try this [guide](http://news.yahoo.com/create-live-system-iso-ubuntu-124722168.html)