# How to create iso from installed Ubuntu 14.04 on Vmware?

Tags: 14.04, iso

I want to create an Ubuntu 14.04 iso with is all installed packages and software.
Ubuntu is installed on Vmware workstation.

I want to be able to install this iso on new systems.

Comment: Have you done any investigations yourself? - anything you add to your question will help us to help you.

Comment: Or http://askubuntu.com/questions/339412/how-to-make-iso-image-of-current-logged-in-system-to-use-it-as-future-installati or http://askubuntu.com/questions/560334/create-live-iso-from-installed-ubuntu-with-data-for-future-install-like-super-os

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an ISO image using [systemback](http://sourceforge.net/projects/systemback/)

To install log in to your Ubuntu in VMWARE and in terminal type:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nemh/systemback
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install systemback
```

Then copy the iso image from VMWARE to main desktop and use it to reinstall into a new system.

Comment: Can I use this iso on new system? I don't want this iso for vmware on new machine.

Comment: Yes, it will work.